# Download files from a list

Tags: wget

How can I download files (that are listed in a text file) using `wget` or some other automatic way?

Sample file list:

```
www.example.com/1.pdf
www.example.com/2.pdf
www.example.com/3.pdf
```

Answer (score 274):

`wget` has a built-in flag for this: `wget -i your_list`, where `your_list` is a file containing URL's delimited by linebreaks.
You can find this kind of thing by reading `man wget`

Comment: @aureianimus if I want to skip the link 2 then how?

Comment: This solution worked for me. I was happy with it downloading sequentially and not in parallel.

Answer (score 91):

Get them in parallel with

```
cat urlfile | parallel --gnu "wget {}"
```

By default it will run as many processes as you have cores, you can probably ramp this up another 10x if you really want to pull them down quickly by adding "-j 20" after parallel.

Comment: I for one just can't get it to work. I don't see any proc spawned, switching echo for wget doesn't output anything

Comment: Some earlier ubuntus have a dumb defect in this space: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448887/gnu-parallel-not-working-at-all

Comment: I posted a change that should fix the above.

Comment: Note with the 'it will run as many processes as you have cores' - network bandwidth is likely going to be more of a limiting factor.

Comment: It really depends.  For a large number of small files this can be almost an order of magnitude faster, as most of the transfer time is the handshake/TCP round trip's.  Also in the situation where you are downloading from a number of smaller hosts, sometime the per connection bandwidth is limited, so this will bump things up.

Comment: It works, but shows no output to the console. Is it possible to have some visual feedback?

Comment: OMG, after finishing, it spitted out ALL wget output, thousands of lines showing progress. So, the command is extremely useful but has poor output. Is there a way to improve the output?

Comment: Hahaha.  That is kinda funny.  There is a way to silence wget, try adding the –quiet flag in there?

Comment: Also, I suspect you could port the output of wget to /dev/null if nothing else.

Comment: This is pretty useful if you want to use a list of relative URLs (resource ID without hostnames) with different hostnames, example:

cat urlfile | parallel --gnu "wget http://example1.com{}" and 
cat urlfile | parallel --gnu "wget http://example2.com{}"

Comment: Can this take advantage of keep-alive?

Comment: Also, I should report in all fairness that I typically used this over the 500Mb connection my work hosts.

Comment: Nice trick, super fast

Comment: One might add that flooding a website for a massive amount of parallel requests for large files is not particularly nice. Doesn't matter for big sites, but if it's just a smaller one you should take care.

Answer (score 14):

`parallel` has a built-in flag `--arg-file` (`-a`) that will use an input-file as the source, so you can avoid `cat |`. You can use

```
parallel --gnu -a urlfile wget
```

Or simply `parallel --gnu wget < urlfile`

Answer (score 10):

```
xargs -i wget 'http://{}'  < your_list
```

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '{print "http://" $0;}' list.txt | xargs -l1 wget
```

where list.txt is your list file

Answer (score 5):

I saw Florian Diesch's answer.

I got it to work by including the parameter `bqc` in the command.

```
xargs -i wget -bqc 'http://{}' < download.txt
```

All downloads started in parallel in the background.

- `-b`: Background. Go to background immediately after start
- `-q`: Quiet. Turn off wget's output
- `-c`: Continue. Continue getting a partially-downloaded file

Answer (score 1):

Link file links.txt

Command for down load all links file

```
cat links.txt | wget -i
```

Comment: This does not work. `wget -i links.txt` is the right command.

Comment: No this is not right command. Right command is this : "    cat links.txt | wget -i"

Comment: there is a dash missing

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this:

```
xargs -a download_file -L1 wget
```

It works for me.
Links inside the txt file must be in separate lines.