# Download files with wget from a list but save with a specific naming pattern

Tags: command-line, wget

> This question is ***similar*** to [Download files from a list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103623/download-files-from-a-list) but it is not the same as I want to go beyond this.  Please do not close as a duplicate.

I have a list of files to download in a text file `foo.txt`.  There is a directory `foo` which I'm in, and I use `wget -i ../foo.txt` to pull the files down.  That's all fine and dandy.

However, what I *need* to do is download the files in there with a specific type of naming pattern.  It's pulling down `json` files that are being spit out by API calls to a specific server, but I need it to be saved in a specific pattern such as `foo_1.json`, and because it's not actually linking to a `foo_1.json` file it won't save it as such.

Is there any way to expand upon the `wget` functionality to save files it downloads in a specific filename pattern, say, sequentially?

If not, alternative CLI methods *not* using `wget` are acceptable.

Comment: If `wget` is too unwieldy for this, please feel free to suggest alternative applications and methods.

Comment: What are the filenames that are being downloaded now?

Comment: @jakekimds they're being saved as the part after the first `/` in the API query on the URL - it's not saving as files because it's returned as text not as downloadable JSON files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always use a shell loop:

```
while read url; do wget -O foo_$((++i)).json "$url"; done < list.txt
```

The file `list.txt` is your list of URLs, one per line. This is read by the while loop, each URL is saved as `$url`, wget downloads it and the `-O` flag tells it to save to a file called `foo_N.json` where `N` is the current value of `$i`. Since `$i` is incremented in each iteration (`$((++i))`), this will result in a increasing sequence of file names.

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I need.  Not as neat as a one-liner wget, but it works.  Thanks!