# Send file name from a list.txt to another file one by one

Tags: bash, scripts

I would like to download files from a list.
e.g. `list.txt` is the list file.
It contains the list of file names:

```
pic_01.jpg
pic_02.jpg
pic_xxx.jpg
```

I need a loop which takes out the file name one by one and write it into an another file (just one name). The download script will use this single file name.

To summarize: send a file name from a list to another file, which contains only one file name (probably with a loop).

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but if you have a list of urls in your file, you can use `wget` to download them all in one go. https://askubuntu.com/questions/103623/download-files-from-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file line by line with a `while` loop and `echo` each one to a new file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r l || [[ -n "$l" ]]; do
    echo $l >$(mktemp -p.)
done <list.txt
```

This will loop over every line of `list.txt` and print the whole line to a tempfile created in the current directory. By default `mktemp` uses the template `tmp.XXXXXXXXXX` to create the files – the `X`s are replaced by random characters – you can adapt that to your needs by specifying a different template, e.g. making it `mktemp -p. file.XXXXX`.

Further reading:

- [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929453/6164712)
- `man mktemp`